# gstreamer lower framerate after interruption of data stream

Tags: windows, gstreamer, rtsp, frame-rate

My setup looks like this:

1. An ethernet camera connected to a wireless link node.
2. The camera sends an H264 encoded stream (320*184 at 25 FPS) using UDP.
3. Another wireless link node connected to a laptop (Windows 7).
4. The laptop is running gstreamer.
5. The received UDP packets are used to display the video without any latency.

The gstreamer command to display the videostream:
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=0x00000001 location=rtsp://10.0.0.3:554/stream1 latency=0 drop_on_latency=true ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=800 ! autovideosink

Here is the issue:

1. I interrupt the data stream by removing the ethernet cable between camera and first wireless link node for 5 seconds and then reconnecting the cable. Result: The display of the videostream stops and then recovers.
2. I interrupt the data stream for 15 seconds. Result: The display of the videostream recovers but a very low framerate; About 1 frame per second. If I then restart gstreamer the videostream is again nicely presented.

How can I overcome this reduction in framerate? Automatically restarting gstreamer if this situation is detected would be an option for me.

Regards, doojoo

Comment: Could you try setting sync property of the sink to false? `autovideosink sync=false`

Comment: When setting sync to false the display of the stream recovers nicely!

Answer (score 0):

When setting sync to false, as suggested by Alper, the display of the stream recovers nicely!
What happens now is this:

1. When the data stream stops gstreamer will continue to show the last frame.
2. When the data stream starts again gstreamer stops and my script starts gstreamer again. Then it will present the video at the good framerate.